# How to replace or delete component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component which is trying to delete its child `graph` and replace it with a rendering of new `graph` with different props given to it.

However the new `graph` is not rendered and the old `graph` just re renders itself without updating any states which mean the look doesn't change even though the old child isnt in the rendering array anymore.

```
  render(){


let graph = [];
graph.push(this.MakeGraph(this.state.centerNode));
return(

  graph[graph.length-1]
);
}
```